# Get conflict .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I have one domain on main root folder i'd install wordpress for promotion of my main site and I have subfolder which have core php code now i have only one .htaccess for both site on main root folder in this case there's only one site should working fine either wordpress or core php folder I need condition for htaccess for both working well.

**.htaccess**

```
#for wordpress site
RewriteRule ^(shieldpayments)($|/) - [L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

#for main site
RewriteRule ^(mountainstar|wp_test)($|/) - [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Separate them. Leave wp one in the root. Create separate one for your core site in its folder

Comment: Yes i'd same thing but i'd set rule for hide that folder so this is casing issue